# Positive definite matrix and categorical variables - SEM - (lavaan)

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, categorical-encoding, lavaan

I'm trying to estimate the following SEM model with the *lavaan* package:

```
model <- "
# latent variables definitions
latent1 =~ x1 + x2
# regressions
x3 ~ latent1
y ~ x3 + latent1 + cat1.1 + cat1.2 + ... + cat1.k + cat2.1 + cat2.2 + ... + cat2.(k-1) "
```

There are two categorical variables, cat1 and cat2. According to the package documentation, they are manually encoded by a set of respectively $k$ and $k-1$ variables (the regression model has no intercept, therefore the model matrix shouldn't be singular).

Unfortunately, the *sem* function return the following error message:

```
Error in lav_model_estimate(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavpartable = lavpartable,  : 
  lavaan ERROR: initial model-implied matrix (Sigma) is not positive definite;
  check your model and/or starting parameters.
```

I'm sorry but I can't provide a fully reproducible example. Do you have any idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: Unless Lavaan has idiosyncratically changed the meaning of formulas in `R`, your formula *does* include an intercept.  You have to append `-1` or `+0` to indicate a no-intercept formula.

Comment: You are right: finally found in the *lavaan* documentation, *a one-sided formula, to be applied to data to generate the variables for which covariances or raw moments are computed. The default formula is ~., i.e., all of the variables in the data, including an implied intercept*